# Creating a Pivot in background code from Linq feed

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7

I've currently got a class that gets and dispatches an XML feed using Linq to XML to a ListBox in my XAML page. I took this from a tutorial, and was wondering, would I be able to make it appear in a pivot?

My idea is to load the feed, and create a pivot page just in background code for each item (Something like, foreach item in my data, create a new pivot, with other content)

Is this possible?
I currently get data into a ListBox by Binding the loading and using "TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}"/>" in XAML, and loading the feed in the background code as follows:

```
myFeed.LoadFeed(//name of the listbox that currently has to exist in XAML)
```

Here is my code that loads the XML feed and dispatches to a Listbox

```
public class FeedItem
{
    public string Id { set; get; }
    public string Text { set; get; }

}

public class Feed
{
    ListBox myContext;

    public void LoadFeed(ListBox context)
    {
        myContext = context;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://myDataSource"));
        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), request);
    }


    private static readonly XNamespace m = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata";
    private void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {


        HttpWebRequest request =
            (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
        HttpWebResponse response =
          (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(response.GetResponseStream());

           List<FeedItem> feedItems = (from question in doc.Descendants(m + "properties")
                                        select new FeedItem()
                                        {
                                            Id = question.Descendants().ToList()[0].Value,
                                            Text = question.Descendants().ToList()[1].Value
                                        }).ToList();

            myContext.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { myContext.ItemsSource = feedItems; });






    }
}
```

What can be used to hold the data so it can go in a pivot?
How do i parse the response item-by-item, into a new pivot?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You need to provide a datatemplate to the Pivot control. Give attention to the header template which is defined at Pivote level not on the PivotItem's one.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
<controls:Pivot ItemsSource="{Binding MyPivots}">
    <controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyTitle}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
    <controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <controls:PivotItem>                       
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding YourRssText}" />
            </controls:PivotItem>
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
</controls:Pivot>
```

And the code-behind class:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage{
     public List<RssFeed> MyPivots { get; set; }
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
    MyPivots = new List<RssFeed>
    {
        new RssFeed{ MyTitle = "Title1", YourRssText = "Body1"},
        new RssFeed{ MyTitle = "Title2", YourRssText = "Body2"},
        new RssFeed{ MyTitle = "Title3", YourRssText = "Body3"},
    };
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;

     }
}


public class RssFeed   
{   
   public string MyTitle { get; set; }

   public string YourRssText { get; set; }
 }
```